# SCM for databases

Tags: database, version-control

For a data-driven approach, e.g. for games, data that goes into a database is part of the (generalized) source code for the project. What is the best strategy for version controlling database contents? note: not schema. It needs to have all the properties of a SCM like rollback and branching.

Comment: Did you look at the previous questions on this topic, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=database+version-control?  Specifically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361939/get-my-database-under-version-control-using-a-dvcs-mercurial/3363481#3363481, which points out the pros and cons of SCM vs backups.  If what you want is all the properties of a SCM, then just use SCM, and unless it handles this situation really poorly, just use your existing SCM so you don't have to use 2 for the same project.

Comment: Did you read my question? in this case the contents of the database is semantically part of the source code

Comment: You haven't said what makes your instance of this question different from the others (sure, it's semantically part of the source code), or why you don't just want to use your existing SCM.  If it's semantically part of the source code and you want all the properties of a SCM, the solution seems pretty obvious. In any case, Ry4an's answer that I linked to has some useful observations on why not all normal SCM abilities may be useful in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple text files to hold the contents work well for version control.  Pick a format that is easy to read and write, comma-separated is easiest if you don't have like 500 columns or anything like that.

But this leaves the matter of loading it.  If you have a simple situation, your upgrade/install script can truncate the source tables and reload.  If that is no good because of foreign keys, you have to code a little routine that goes through the text files line-by-line and inserts new values and possibly overwrites changed values.